# SQL - Create view with SUM of the first N row of an ordered group

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this table in my MYSQL db, and I want to create a view as the title.
Table:

```
ID | Result
---+-------
1  | 10
3  | 7
1  | 4
2  | 5
1  | 3
```

The view should select group by ID, SUM(result), and consider only the best 2 results for each ID, and order everything by the result. So..
View:

```
ID | Result
---+--------
1  | 14
3  | 7
2  | 5
```

I tried with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW final_res AS 
SELECT  `ID` , SUM(  `result` ) 
FROM  `result_table`
GROUP BY  `ID`
HAVING COUNT(*)<=2
ORDER BY `result`
```

But this doesn't work. :/

Comment: Can you explain what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: ID with more than 2 count(*) are not in the view.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a row number using `user-defined variables` within each group ordered by the `result desc`, and then limit the `sum` to the first 2 rows within each group:

```
select id, sum(result)
from (
  select id, result, @rn:=if(@prevId=ID,@rn+1,1) rn, @prevId:=id
  from result_table join (select @rn:=0, @previd:=0) t
  order by id, result desc
  ) t
where rn <= 2
group by id
order by 2 desc
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f55dd/2)

---

Alternatively, you could use a correlated subquery, but I think the row number approach is a bit cleaner:

```
select t.id, max(t.result) + coalesce((
  select max(t2.result)
  from result_table t2 
  where t.id = t2.id and t.result != t2.result
  ),0)
from result_table t
group by id
order by 2 desc
```

- [Additional Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f55dd/5)

Comment: This doesn't works for views: "View's SELECT contains a variable or parameter"

Comment: @daimpa -- I supplied a 2nd approach without using `user-defined-variables`... Didn't realize you were creating a view.

Comment: If I've two identical result for the ID, it doesn't work. I can have identical results for my IDs :/

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get anything because you're grouping on ID, your HAVING clause is saying where there's more than one ID. This will never happen

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW final_res AS 
SELECT TOP 2 `ID` , SUM(  `result` ) 
FROM  `result_table`
GROUP BY  `ID`
ORDER BY `result` desc
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't want to exclude ID that have 3 or more in results, I just want that only the 2 BEST results are counted.